# Multiple Threads reading from the same file

Tags: c#, xml, file, foreach, parallel-processing

I have a xml file that needs to be read from many many times.  I am trying to use the Parallel.ForEach to speed this processes up since none of that data being read in is relevant as to what order it is being read in. The data is just being used to populate objects.  My problem is even though I am opening the file each time in the thread as read only it complains that it is open by another program.  (I don't have it opened in a text editor or anything :))

How can I accomplish multi reads from the same file?

EDIT: The file is ~18KB pretty small.  It is read from about 1,800 times.

Thanks

Comment: Your hard drive still only has one head so you can only do one read at a time. What performance improvement are you expecting from this?

Comment: Doe the file fit into disk cache? If so, then multiple reads will be fast, otherwise if the file is small enough to fit into memory, then use a memory mapped file instead and read from that. Otherwise the harddisk will spend a lot of time thrashing rather than performing sequential reads, and you will loose performance rather than gain it.

Comment: One head on a harddisk? I am pretty sure even single platter drives have multiple heads these days as well as caching, etc that address head specific slowdowns.

Comment: @GrayWizardx: Way to go for missing the point :)

Comment: @Timwi guess I did. Which point? I provided an alternate solution that addresses the multiple reads. Strictly specifying FileShare.Read would have fixed the error but not the problem.

Comment: @GrayWizardx: I was only referring to the above comment, not to your answer.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

If you want multiple threads to read from the same file, you need to specify `FileShare.Read`:

```
using (var stream = File.Open("theFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    ...
}
```

However, you will not achieve any speedup from this, for multiple reasons:

1. Your hard disk can only read one thing at a time. Although you have multiple threads running at the same time, these threads will all end up waiting for each other.
2. You cannot easily parse a part of an XML file. You will usually have to parse the entire XML file every time. Since you have multiple threads reading it all the time, it seems that you are not expecting the file to change. If that is the case, then why do you need to read it multiple times?

Comment: +1 For the "1" and "2" comments. FileAccess.Read and FileShare.Read will NOT solve the issue, when multiple threads are trying to read the same file. So as mentioned in the "2" comment if we only need to read it, then we can first read it once and then give to "do the processing" for multiple threads.

Comment: Regarding point 1, this not be applicable to things like disk arrays, which for server software, would be easy to expect.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the size of the file and the type of reads you are doing it might be faster to load the file into memory first, and then provide access to it directly to your threads.

You didnt provide any specifics on the file, the reads, etc so I cant say for sure if it would address your specific needs.

The general premise would be to load the file once in a single thread, and then either directly (via the Xml structure) or indirectly (via XmlNodes, etc) provide access to the file to each of your threads. I envision something similar to:

1. Load the file
2. For each Xpath query dispatch the matching nodes to your threads.

If the threads dont modify the XML directly, this might be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 3):

When you open the file, you need to specify `FileShare.Read` :

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("theFile.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    ...
}
```

That way the file can be opened multiple times for reading

Comment: whilst that is correct, unless the poster partitions the file into blocks, it is dubious that any real speedup will occur using multiple threads.

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: indeed. But I'm just answering the OP's question, not judging whether using multiple threads is a good idea ;)

Answer (score -1):

While an old post, it seems to be a popular one so I thought I would add a solution that I have used to good effect for multi-threaded environments that need read access to a file. The file must however be small enough to hold in memory at least for the duration of your processing, and the file must only be read and not written to during the period of shared access.

```
string FileName = "TextFile.txt";
string[] FileContents = File.ReadAllLines(FileName);

foreach (string strOneLine in FileContents)
{
  // Do work on each line of the file here
}
```

So long as the file is only being read, multiple threads or programs can access and process it at the same time without treading on one another's toes.