# OK to have multiple processes reading from the same text file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ntfs

I've inherited development responsibilities for a set of .NET projects which include Windows services, an ASP.NET website and standard executables which are launched via task manager.

All of these components connect to a MySQL database.  Currently, the encrypted connection string is located in the individual app.config/web.config files.  I think it's kind of a pain to have to update the connection string in multiple places, so I had the idea to put the connection string in a text file which would be accessed by all the individual components.

Before I move full-steam ahead on that, I wanted to ask if I might be introducing a bug since there could potentially be multiple processes trying to access this text file at the same time.  I've written a universal method for reading the text file, and I was careful to ensure that the file is being opened in "Read" mode:

```
public string AESDecryptFromFile(string path, string password, string IV)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(path))
            throw new Exception("File not found: " + path);

        string cryptogram;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                cryptogram = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim(new char[] { '\r', '\n', ' ' });
            }
        }
        return AESDecrypt(cryptogram, password, IV);
    }
```

I don't have any reason to believe that the processes would lock the file if I implement it this way, but I thought I'd ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you try testing it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527205/multiple-threads-reading-from-the-same-file

Comment: @mason - I meant to mention that I don't have enough traffic in my development environment to effectively prove this out.  I suppose I could have written a test program that spawned multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default with the `(string path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)` constructor of `FileStream` will get the following configuration as well:

- FileShare = FileShare.Read
- bufferSize = 4096
- useAsync = false

Because you don't want the process to lock the file, this will be perfect for you as you'll require Read only (See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx)

However if you want to be explicit you can use the following constructor:

```
FileStream s = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

Until you do not change the file it's OK. It makes problems when you want to write or write and read at multiple threads, because you don't know which one thread will write/read end/start first so you can't predict any behaviour

Answer (score -1):

I think you might need to tell your FileStream constructor how you want to share the  file? ["fileshare"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare(v=vs.110).aspx)