# Reading file from network share will file be locked for other threads

Tags: c#

I'm needing to access files from a network share but my concern is more about whether reading the same file from the network share at the same time in multiple threads will encounter problems?  I need to send back the file from the network share to the calling application in memory.

Will this lock the file whilst the given thread is reading the contents?

The code is a C# Web API application that returns files.

Thanks

**Some more information**

I have updated the apps application pool as the user that has access to the network share and it seems to work.

Comment: See this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527205/multiple-threads-reading-from-the-same-file

Comment: @user7396598: The thing is, that this is a network share. So there will be the NFS even before NTFS/FAT.

Comment: ah ok thanks for this, I wasn't sure if using FileAccess.Read would do it, sounds like it does!

Comment: What do you mean @Christopher? - I assume you can grab a network shared file and send it back in memory?

Comment: The linked answer is regardless of network share.  In order to prevent his application thread from locking the file he has to include the FileShare option.

Comment: @user7396598: Mostly I am wondering if the lock could even "penetrate" down to NTFS. SMB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block) defines a seperate set of read/write persmissions. And even rules to how many users can share access to a file/folder. I have no idea if it will have any effect on this. But I thought it worth mentioning that the linked answer is only valid for Programm -> NTFS access. Not Programm -> SMB -> NTFS access. So oddities/extra problems might appear not covered in the linked answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer @Christopher, I guess that leads me to wonder what the best approach is?